# Cyrillic symbols are displayed incorrectly

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I'm trying to pass some information from a browser to my server and end up having '????' symbols. I thoroughly searched for this problem on the Internet and StackOverFlow but in the end nothing helped me. My assumption is Thymeleaf/Spring continues to use ISO_8859_1 charset instead of UTF-8.
DispatcherServlet(CharacterEncodingFilter):

```
public class DispatcherServlet extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext aServletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(aServletContext);
        registerCharacterEncodingFilter(aServletContext);
        registerHiddenFieldFilter(aServletContext);

    }

    private void registerHiddenFieldFilter(ServletContext aContext) {
        aContext.addFilter("hiddenHttpMethodFilter",
                new HiddenHttpMethodFilter()).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");
    }

    private void registerCharacterEncodingFilter(ServletContext aContext) {
        EnumSet<DispatcherType> dispatcherTypes = EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST,
        DispatcherType.FORWARD);

        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic characterEncoding = aContext.addFilter("characterEncoding",
        characterEncodingFilter);
        characterEncoding.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, true, "/*");
    }

}
```

My Configuration:

```
public class ApplicationConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private final Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    public ApplicationConfiguration(ApplicationContext applicationContext, 
    Environment environment) {

        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry resourceHandlerRegistry) {
        resourceHandlerRegistry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").
        addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    // Themyleaf resolver,engine etc
    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        engine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
        engine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return engine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver =  new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }
}
```

As I've already said, I'm trying to make Spring/Thymeleaf use UTF-8 charset instead of the standard one. Certainly I could use something like

```
byte[] bytes = content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
content = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

but I'd like to have it done by Spring/Thymeleaf if it's possible.

**UPD:** Whatever the input data is I always see '???' in the console. For instance: 'Текстовая строка123' produces '???µ???????????°?? ???????????°123' (except for Non Cyrillic symbols)

Comment: Whatever the input data is I always see '???' in the console. For instance:  'Текстовая строка123' produces  ???µ???????????°?? ???????????°123

Comment: Post those details as edits to your Question, not as Comments.